# Update multiple fragments with same layout after doing Async Task in TabLayout and ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I'm using **TabLayout** and **ViewPager2** in order to show up to 3 fragments with same layout. A fragment per tab.

All 3 fragments should update his own ListView after an Async Task is completed. All fragments share the same layout but each fragment has its own ListView content.

The Async Task is fired when user clicks a specific button.

I think the entire code would be a mess so here is the main code, I think should be enough:

***MainActivity.class***

```
// here we fire the async task if "buttonrefesh" is clicked

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.buttonrefresh) //refresh
        new FetchAnuncios().execute();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,(tab, position) -> tab.setIcon(icons[position])).attach();
}
```

***MyPagerAdapter.class***

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case 0: {
                return Fragment_ma.newInstance("fragment 1");
            }
            case 1: {
                return Fragment_ma.newInstance("fragment 2");
            }
            case 2: {
                return Fragment_ma.newInstance("fragment 3");
            }
            default:
                return Fragment_ma.newInstance("fragment 1, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return 3;}
}
```

}

***Fragment_ma.class***

```
public class Fragment_ma extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ma, container, false);
    return v;
}

public static Fragment_ma newInstance(String text) {

    Fragment_ma f = new Fragment_ma();
    return f;
}
```

}

***FetchAnuncios.class***

```
    private class FetchAnuncios extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<AnuncioData>> {        
    
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<AnuncioData> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        ArrayList<AnuncioData> arrayList = new ArrayList<AnuncioData>();

        // here we do some I/O work to get arrayList with all the data that should be attached to each fragment ListView
        return arrayList;

    }

    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<AnuncioData> arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
        
        final ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list); // I know here is the problem, but can't imagine how to solve it
        
        list.setAdapter(null);
        if (arrayList.size()>0) {
            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
            list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }


    }
}
```

As you can see, the method "onPostExecute" is the one that should update the 3 ListView's of each fragment with the data stored on the arrayList (different content on each ListView). How can I achieve this? Fragments are created when I click to the tab, not before (except the first one which is initially visible). So when should I attach the listview adapter and how?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with this part of code hope it will help and remove this part of code
"list.setAdapter(null);"

```
if (arrayList.size()>0) {
    if(int i=0; i<arrayList.size()-1; i++){
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList.get(i));
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
      }
    }
```

Comment: How will this code help? This will only update one ListView, the one in Tab1

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.
Main changes:

- Create MyPagerAdapter in doBackground
- Pass arrayList to MyPagerAdapter instance before setting the adapter to viewpager
- set list adapter on fragment list class (onCreate)